# How to create an event if you have multiple calendar - Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am trying to create a calendar event problematically. Below code is working file but the issue is when i start the activity its pop two calendar (com.android.calendar , com.google.android.calendar).

How to select any of one?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a chooser and allow the user to select on which Calendar app they want to save the event.

```
Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Calendar");
```

You code with the modification:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Calendar"));
```

Comment: No, as both calendar name is same. when i am executing the code It says there is no app :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed two calendar application on device but generally this is not the case , generally device have one calendar app by default.

I would recommend you to do not do anything in this condition for following reason.

```
1) Generally device having only one calendar app
2) If you choose a particular calendar then the devices which not installed your specified calendar won't able to use you app.
3) If person has installed two calendar let him decide which he want to use to add event, which is recommended by Google.
```

Comment: com.android.calendar , com.google.android.calendar both are google calendar only that is the reason i am not able to figure it out how to handle it.

Comment: I can suggest simple solution uninstall one Google Calendar. Because generally people don't have two Google calendar you don't need to do anything.

Comment: These are system app ..i think we can not remove also.

Comment: Generally there is only one Calendar system app.   Have tried to uninstall both or just tried one??